# I am trying to get my button animation to reverse its animation when I stop hovering over

Tags: html, css

the yellow line that increases has an animation but I don't know how to get it when I stop hovering over the button it will reverse the yellow line animation to its original form instead of just instantly going back I tried using transitions to see if that would work but it didn't I also tried searching online but nothing I needed came up. I tried to add an animation fill mode to see if that would work but it didn't usually transition works for me but not here it might be because of an animation being inside of a on hover  but im not sure I checked other posts but It was to complicated and I tried to replicate what they did but I couldn't get it to work. Also I am trying to get it to reverse from where its at so if it was half way filled then it would reverse from halfway

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2&family=Kablammo&family=Rubik+80s+Fade&family=VT323&display=swap');



html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #27282c;
}

a
{
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Rubik 80s Fade';
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.line
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 53.39%;
  left: 43.97%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fec700;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 10s;
}

a:before
{
  content:  '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 2px;
  background: #27282c;
}

a span
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

/*-  Above  is  Main  Parts -*/


a:hover + .line
{
 animation: a 4s;
}


/*- Keyframes Below -*/

@keyframes a
{

0% {}  
20% {width: 174px;}
40% {width: 174px;top: 53.39%;height: 2px;}
60% {width: 174px;top: 53.39%;height: 2px;}
80% {width: 174px;top:  24.74em;height: 45px;}
100% {width: 174px;top: 24.74em;height: 45px;}
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="mini" style="--clr:#49ea"><span>Button</span></a>
</body>
<!-- Line Not in Body -->

<line class="line" id="lni"></line>

</html>
```

the lines weird cause its not on a full page